# pyqt dialog not showing a second time

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a pyqt app where I want a dialog to display when I click a menu item. If the dialog loses focus and the menu item is clicked again, it brings the dialog to the front. This is working fine so far.

The problem is that when the dialog is opened and then closed, clicking the menu item doesnt create/display a new dialog. I think I know why, but can't figure out a solution

Heres the code:

```
from ui import mainWindow, aboutDialog

class ReadingList(QtGui.QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.about = None

        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(self.showAbout)

    def showAbout(self):
        # If the about dialog does not exist, create one
        if self.about is None:
            self.about = AboutDialog(self)
            self.about.show()
        # If about dialog exists, bring it to the front
        else:
            self.about.activateWindow()
            self.about.raise_()

class AboutDialog(QtGui.QDialog, aboutDialog.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    readingList = ReadingList()
    readingList.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem lies in the fact that when the dialog is created the first time, `self.about` is no longer `None`. This is good because the conditional in `showAbout()` allows me to bring the dialog to the front instead of creating a new one (the else condition)

However, when the dialog is closed, `self.about` is no longer `None` due to the previous dialog creation, which means it doesn't create a new one and just jumps to the else condition

How can I make it so that dialogs can be created after the first?

I thought about overriding the `closeEvent` method in the `AboutDialog` class but I'm not sure how to get a reference to `readingList` to send a message back saying the dialog has been closed. Or maybe I'm overthinking it, maybe the return from `self.about.show()` can be used somehow?

(I know I can probably avoid all of this using modal dialogs but want to try to figure this out)

Comment: In `AboutDialog`'s `super(...).__init__()` pass the `parent` argument like: `super(...).__init__(parent)`. Now you won't have to worry about bringing the dialog to front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this, but here's one possibility:

```
class ReadingList(QtGui.QMainWindow, mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ReadingList, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)    
        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(self.showAbout)
        self.about = None

    def showAbout(self):
        if self.about is None:
            self.about = AboutDialog(self)
            self.about.show()
            self.about.finished.connect(
                lambda: setattr(self, 'about', None))
        else:
            self.about.activateWindow()
            self.about.raise_()

class AboutDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AboutDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
```

(NB: you should never use `self.__class__` with `super` as it can lead to an infinite recursion under certain circumstances. Always pass in the subclass as the first argument - unless you're using Python 3, in which case you can omit all the arguments).